# How to create shortcuts to application on the desktop on Linux Mint 18 or up?

Tags: linux-mint, shortcuts, desktop

I want to create a shortcut to my program on the desktop on Linux Mint 18, but I simply can't find any ways to do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

#### Method 1 (directories)

Go to the folder you want, right Click and select ***Make Link***, then drag and drop it on the Desktop

[image: Make Link]

#### Method 2

Find your application through the Linux Mint menu, right Click and press ***Add to Desktop***

[image: Add to Desktop]

#### Method 3

Right click on the Desktop and press ***Create Launcher***

The pop up window will ask you to either enter a terminal command that will launch it, or browse through the directories.

[image: Create Launcher]

#### Method 4

Create a symlink

[image: Symlink shortcut]

> **Note:** To successfully create a symlink you have to provide the full path, otherwise you could get a broken link. Generally a symlink syntax is `ln -s SOURCE DESTINATION`.
>
> You do not need to specify a filename in the `DESTINATION`, just where you need to place it

Answer (score 12):

Or, even easier, just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag and drop your file/executable.

Unless they changed that from 17.3 to 18.x, but doubt it.

Comment: According to here: https://www.faqforge.com/linux/create-shortcuts-in-linux-symbolic-links/ you only need Ctrl+Shift, which worked for me on 19.1

Comment: Upvoted! It is still there in Linux mint 19.

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch Nautilus (the file manager).
2. In Nautilus, click on Computer.
3. From there, navigate to /usr/share/applications.
4. Find the icon of the program you want a shortcut for, click on it, and type Ctrl+C to copy.
5. In Nautilus, click on Desktop in the left pane.
6. Type Ctrl+V to copy the shortcut to the desktop.
7. Right-click your new shortcut, click Properties, click on the Permissions tab, and make sure that the Allow executing file as program box is ticked.
8. X out of the Properties dialog and also out of Nautilus.

Enjoy your new desktop shortcut!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. If you have a new question, please post a new question, referencing this one as necessary. I have edited your answer to remove the "question" portion. Only answers are allowed in the answer box. Also, please cite a source for your answer if it is someone else's work.

Comment: you should of moved it then and pm'ed me as to why. NOT edited to remove whe issue i came here about.

Comment: No offense intended. I cannot post a question on your behalf. You may roll back my edit if you wish but then you'll need to fix it yourself as the answer can't remain in it's original form.

Answer (score 1):

from Linuxmint forum [Creating shortcuts](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=237708)

> In the file manager (Nemo) open the View menu > Extra Pane.
> Open the Desktop folder in one pane, and the source folder in the other pane.
> Click on the folder or file you want to symlink.
> Hold down SHIFT-CTRL and drag the folder to the other pane. A symlink will be magically created.

Answer (score 1):

> On Linux Mint 19, Linux Mint 20.

Open File Manager, navigate to the location (where file is located).

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Drag and Drop to your Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

All that is super fancy, a simple text file, go to properties, permissions, tick allow «executing file as program».

From now, simply by double clicking this file, the tasks will be performed. (bash!)

For example, this will launch Firefox, if installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox
```

How cool is that?

Comment: Worth noting that this will not result in a Firefox icon being displayed in the taskbar when run. Instead, it will show an icon for a generic bash script.

Answer (score 1):

Sample for Firefox developer:

1- Create ~/.local/share/applications/firex-dev.desktop

2- paste:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=FirexFox Dev
Icon=/opt/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Exec= "/opt/firefox-dev/firefox"
Comment=Internet b for developer
Categories=Development;Internet;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Knoppix: drag & release app to desktop. A menu shows up...click on 'link here'