# How do I drag a link to the desktop in Linux Mint using Chromium?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, chromium

On Windows, I'm very much used to dragging a link from the browser's address bar onto my desktop and having a shortcut created for me for later reading.

I'd like to do this on Linux Mint. It works in Firefox, but not with Chromium browser. I know I can [create shortcuts myself](https://superuser.com/questions/1219947/how-to-create-shortcuts-to-application-on-the-desktop-on-linux-mint-18-or-up) (e.g. using Create Launcher), but I like the ease of use of drag-and-drop.

Any idea why this simple thing doesn't work with Chromium?

Comment: Can you clarify how you drag a link from the Firefox address bar to the desktop in Mint?

Comment: @fixer1234 You drag the icon to the left of the address bar, and it creates a shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: My FF v67.0 on Mint doesn't have any such draggable icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8jle.png

Comment: @fixer1234: The lock icon is supposed to be it.

Comment: @harrymc, the lock icon doesn't do anything on mine if you drag and drop it.

Comment: @fixer1234: Then I think that you have duplicated the poster's problem.

Comment: @harrymc, no.  The OP says Firefox does it for them but Chromium doesn't.  I don't use Chromium, although a Chromium-based browser doesn't do it.  But FF doesn't do it either.

Comment: @Gigi, the plot thickens.  This appears to be affected by what desktop environment you have on Mint.  When I posted the other day, I was in Cinnamon, and neither Firefox nor Vivaldi (Chromium-based) would work.  I tested it just now with Xfce (also Mint v19.1).  Both browsers created a link when dragging the icon to the desktop.  So it's DE-specific.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm using MATE. And just to clarify, yes, I was dragging the lock icon.

Comment: If that feature is important to you, you might want to check out Xfce.  The UI is pretty similar to Mate.  There are a couple of differences in bundled utilities, but you can always just add any Mate-specific utilities you prefer.  You could try just adding the Xfce desktop to Mint (might need to augment what's defined in the meta package).  If /home is in a separate partition, it can be pretty straightforward to just reinstall Mint using the Xfce version.  Or using Mint Backup makes the task simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this issue with Chromium in KDE. I found that dragging the address itself will prompt you for options, including "link here" which is what you want. It's two steps and names the new (.desktop) shortcut with the address instead of the page title but it works.

Note that when dragging the address, Chrome should highlight all of it. If that doesn't happen, click elsewhere to defocus and then drag from the address again. You can also manually select the whole address and then drag.

Also note that KDE shows the keyboard shortcut for the "link here" option is CTRL + SHIFT. However, that seems to create a local, unformatted copy of the website so it's pretty useless.

Comment: Thanks, in fact my solution was eventually to switch to KDE. I did not specify in my question that I was using MATE, and had similar problems using Ubuntu (GNOME).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do that on Windows:

- Launch Chrome and open the website in a regular tab
- Click the three dots in the upper-right corner
- Move the mouse over *More Tools*, and then click *Create Shortcut...*
- In the dialog box enter the name of the shortcut for the application launcher
- Tick "Open as window" for the web app to open in its own window with native controls. Otherwise it’ll just open in a new Chrome tab.
- Finally, click the *Add* button.

Comment: This seems to install the webpage as an app... which although cool to learn, is not quite what I was after. I simply wanted a way to create a shortcut to a website on my desktop by dragging the icon next to the URL, just like I do in every other browser.

Comment: I fired up an old Linux Mint 18 virtual machine and installed Chromium. It doesn't work too well, but I can create a link by dragging the icon to the desktop. I was flabbergasted to find that unlike on Windows, this on Linux Mint does NOT create a URL link. Instead Chromium copies the entire HTML code for the page into a desktop file, which is certainly **not** what you would like. I'm astonished to find that the same also happens for Firefox.

Comment: My conclusion is that on Linux Mint dragging the icon, even when it works, does not achieve your purpose which is to create a link.

Comment: What you describe is quite shocking, but with MATE desktop, I can confirm that dragging the icon to desktop from Firefox does create a desktop link correctly. Quite frankly, this leaves me scratching my head. As per comments under my question, perhaps this behaviour is linked to the desktop environment.

Comment: My Linux Mint 18 uses KDE. From what you say, the result seems indeed to be very dependent on the desktop. Perhaps the interactions of Firefox and Chrome with the desktop are different enough that one works in MATE but the other doesn't. It seems to me that apart from trying out other desktops, your only other option is to raise this as a bug report for Chromium.

Comment: As of Feb 2024 there is no "Create shortcut..." in "More Tools".